# GhostScript dll for WinRT?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-runtime, ghostscript, hololens

I'm using GhostScript (AGPL release, GhostScript 9.21 for Windows 32 bit) in my Unity HoloLens project to convert pdfs. I'm able to run the GhostScript code and convert pdfs in the Editor, but when I try to do so in the HoloLens it returns a DllNotFoundException.

I've tried rebuilding the app multiple times, placing the dll in a variety of locations (every single folder in the App directory), re-downloading a fresh dll from the GhostScript website, and configuring the dll using the Plugin Inspector.

**EDIT Update:** As it turns out, Ghostscript dlls aren't compatible with WinRT environments, which is what I understand the HoloLens to be, which is why the dll is never 'found' because it is not compatible.

Running through [ghostscripts documentation](https://ghostscript.com/doc/9.21/Make.htm), there is a section on how to build Ghostscript from source for Microsoft WinRT environments.

**EDIT Update 2:** The doc specifies how to build using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012's command line. But it's not very clear to an inexperienced user.

I've the code that's called when I try to build it:

nmake -f psi\msvc32.mak SBR=1 DEVSTUDIO= METRO=1 debug && nmake -f psi\msvc32.mak DEVSTUDIO= METRO=1 debugbsc

And the errors returned:

[image: gs errors on build pic]

**EDIT Update 3:** According to an SO user (who is affiliated with GhostScript and  that checked with the developer who originally did the port to WinRT environments) it is suspected that this is simply bit-rot. "Apparently the build has not been checked for a long time, years in fact. Most likely some code has shifted or new source files been added/old ones removed. It should be entirely possible to bring the makefile up to date".

Anyone technically sound enough to do this, walk me through it, or anyone with a previously built GS 32-bit dll for the winRt environment mind passing the file along?

Comment: What variety of locations? The DLL search path is fairly predictable and the easiest location is alongside your application.

Comment: You aren't directly using Ghostscript, you are either using Ghostscript.NET or Ghostscriptsharp. I'd suggest you add the relevant tag (depending which one you use) to this question in place of Ghostscript, you are more likely to get relevant help I would think.

Comment: @Joey I've placed the dll at a number of different locations attempting to reference it from these locations.

Comment: @KenS I went ahead and removed a tag to add ghostscriptsharp as I am truly not sure if it is. As well I edited the op to include which release/version.